# How can I have multiple objects moving at once in PYGAME

Tags: python, class, pygame

I want to make a game where I have enemies coming from two sides of the screen.
Right now I have it so that enemies scroll across the screen one at a time.
I would like to have more then one come at a time slowly increasing how often they come across. 
This is my code

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
winW = 1000
winH = 600
surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((winW, winH),0,32)


pygame.display.set_caption ('Moving Orc')

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, char, startY, startX):
        self.char=char
        self.startY=startY
        self.startX=startX
        self.drawChar()

    def drawChar (self):
        self.space = pygame.image.load (self.char)
        self.spaceRect = self.space.get_rect ()
        self.spaceRect.topleft = (self.startX,self.startY)
        self.moveChar()

    def moveChar (self):
        if self.startX == 0:
            self.xMoveAmt = 5
        elif self.startX == 800:
            self.xMoveAmt = -5

        while True:
            surface.fill ((255,255,255))
            self.spaceRect.left += self.xMoveAmt

            surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)

            pygame.display.update()

            time.sleep (0.02)

            if self.spaceRect.right >= winW:
                surface.fill ((255,255,255))
                break

            elif self.spaceRect.left <= 0:
                surface.fill ((255,255,255))
                break


#MAINLINE
while True:
    enemyList=[]
    leftOrRight = random.randint(0,1)
    if leftOrRight == 0:
        leftOrRight = 0
    elif leftOrRight == 1:
        leftOrRight = 800
    enemyList.append(Enemy(("orc.png"), random.randint(50, 500), leftOrRight))

    for i in range (0,len(enemyList)):
        enemyList[i].drawChar()
        break
```

I have it so that every time you go into the loop, it resets the list which it runs through the class I made. And one guy will go across the screen from the left or right.

Where would i even start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things that you should fix in order to have multiple enemies.

**How a simple pygame program structure look like**

```
init() 
While(True):
    draw()
    update()
    checkInput()
```

I see you already wrote a draw and move functions for the enemy, but they don't do what they should.

Your draw method loads the image, and calls a move function. Loading should be usually done in the `__init__()`.

Your move function draws and moves the character, but it has a While loop, which makes it stuck until that character is out of the screen.

A example solution:

```
def draw(self,surface):
    surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)

def move(self):
    self.spaceRect.left += self.xMoveAmt
    if self.spaceRect.right >= winW:
        self.kill()
    elif self.spaceRect.left <= 0:
        self.kill()
```

a possible way to kill an object is to set a flag, and in the While method, check if it can be removed from the list of objects.

Now you can create a list of enemies, and call draw, and update for each of them. In a for loop.

Comment: I would argue that even having a `draw` function in the `Enemy` class is bad.  Even when changing it so that you must pass in a reference to a surface, you're still restricting how the object's surface gets drawn.  I prefer just giving the object properties for its image and letting the game loop or a utility module handle how it gets drawn in various scenarios.  Edit:  Also, it adds more dependencies to Pygame.  You could theoretically load the image outside of the class and pass the loaded surface into the class's constructor, and make it usable with multiple frameworks.

Comment: I agree that the draw function is not the way to go in a bigger project. That's why I called it a simple pygame program.
The OP's game area is the screen area itself, so the sprite's coords will be the same as the screen ones. There is no point in overcomplicating a simple game

Comment: I now have it so that multiple span and scroll accross the screen. how can I make it so that the spawning and moving dont happen at the same time? Everytime it moves one more spawns filling the screen too quickly.

Comment: @StephenSparks you can track time from the last spawning with the Time module of pygame: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html

Comment: Ok, i got that fine. How can i delete an object when it reaches the other side?

Comment: I already answered that question, check for isDead in a for loop, and remove them from the list. isDead would return true when it is out of screen

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `drawChar` function; it's bad practice to make the Enemy class aware of the `surface` which should only exist in the game logic.  Change the `moveChar` function so that it just updates the object's position.  Take the loop out of `moveChar` and handle the movement in your main gameloop.

The **Enemy** class:

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, char, startX=0, startY=0, xMovAmnt=0):
        self.char = char
        self.x = startX
        self.y = startY
        self.xMovAmnt = xMovAmnt
        # no reason to load the image every time you want to draw, do it here
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.char)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveChar(self):
        self.x += self.xMovAmnt
```

The **Game Loop**:

```
enemyList = []
while True:
    ...
    # you never specified when you want to create a new Enemy, 
    #    so you need to figure that out on your own
    ...

    # this is a more "Pythonic" way of looping over a list than using a range
    for enemy in enemyList:
        enemy.movChar()
        surface.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.x, enemy.y))

    pygame.display.update()
```